# how to access login name to mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, session

this is my login user name php code

```
<p align="center">username: <?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']; ?></p>
```

and this is mysql query

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `carddetail` where drivername='open' ORDER BY `carddetail_cardno` ASC LIMIT $from, $max_results";
```

how can i put this drivername in this where drivername='open'
supose if my driver login is her name so query show only her name data

how can i put

in to this

`where drivername='<?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']; ?>`'

when i put like this its showing this error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in E:\home.php on line 210

please help me to fix this issue 
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use like this:

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `carddetail` 
  where 
  drivername='{$_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']}' 
  ORDER BY `carddetail_cardno` ASC LIMIT $from, $max_results";
```

However, this way is not safe, you can use mysql_real_escape_string():

```
  $drivername = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `carddetail` 
  where 
  drivername='$drivername' 
  ORDER BY `carddetail_cardno` ASC LIMIT $from, $max_results";
```

Or switch to PDO or MySQLI and use prepared statement (parameterized Query)

Answer (score 0):

use as below:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `carddetail` where drivername='". $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] ."' ORDER BY `carddetail_cardno` ASC LIMIT $from, $max_results";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are opening `PHP` tags in `$query` variable which is already in `PHP`.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'])){
$session_fname = $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'];
}

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `carddetail` where drivername= $session_fname ORDER BY `carddetail_cardno` ASC LIMIT $from, $max_results";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use MySQLi or PDO as the `mysql_` functions are now deprecated.

```
$db   = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $db_name);
$name = $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'];

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM carddetail WHERE drivername = ? ORDER BY `carddetail_cardno` ASC LIMIT $from, $max_results");
$stmt->bind_param("si", $name);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```